# In a fluid flow, how do you tell if negative acceleration is deceleration or change in direction?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acceleration

When solving for the acceleration of a fluid flow, you use the equation: (∂u/∂t)+u(∂u/∂x)+v(∂u/∂y). If the solution at a given u and v are negative, how do you know if the flow has a negative acceleration or if it's changing direction?

Comment: And the difference is? Acceleration is acceleration.

Comment: If the acceleration is negative, it could mean the fluid's path has reversed direction or its velocity is decreasing. If I got a negative acceleration after solving the equation, how would I know which is the case?

Comment: The geometry of the problem is apparently one dimensional (There's only one displacement variable in your equation). How could the path reverse without the velocity decreasing first?

Comment: Note: You haven't written down an equation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acceleration of a fluid element $\mathbf a$ is the material derivative of the elements velocity $\mathbf u$:
$$\frac{D\mathbf{a}}{Dt} = \frac{\partial \mathbf u}{\partial t} + \mathbf u \cdot\nabla\mathbf u.$$
In a two dimensional flow, this expression can be expanded to:
$$\frac{D\mathbf{a}}{Dt} = \frac{\partial \mathbf u}{\partial t} + u\frac{\partial\mathbf u}{\partial x} + v\frac{\partial\mathbf u}{\partial y}$$
where $u$ and $v$ are respectively the $x$ and $y$-components of the velocity vector $\mathbf u$.

Telling whether this acceleration will change the magnitude of the velocity vector or change its direction is quite simple, and is just like we do in classical particle mechanics: if $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf u$ are parallel, then $\mathbf a$ only changes the magnitude of $\mathbf u$ (acceleration if $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf u$ point in the same direction, and deceleration if they point in opposite directions). If $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf u$ are not parallel to one another, i.e if $\mathbf a$ points in a different direction to that of $\mathbf u$, then we can decompose $\mathbf a$ into two vectors: one which is parallel to $\mathbf u$, called the tangential acceleration $\mathbf a_t$, and another which is normal to $\mathbf u$ and is thus called the normal acceleration $\mathbf a_n$. The total acceleration is the sum of these two components:
$$\mathbf a = \mathbf a_t + \mathbf a_n,$$
and just like classical mechanics, $\mathbf a_t$ only changes the magnitude of $\mathbf u$ while $\mathbf a_n$ only changes its direction. If $\mathbf a$ is normal to $\mathbf u$, then $\mathbf a = \mathbf a_n$ and thus only the direction of $\mathbf u$ is changed.